# Will ghc-options of an executable override ghc-options of linked libraries?

Tags: haskell

I have a main Haskell executable program with a cabal file. There, I specify the `ghc-options`.

This executable links against other libraries out in the wilderness. Will the `ghc-options` of the cabal files of these libraries be ignored?

I'm basically wondering whether the executable's `ghc-options` will be used for the entire enchilada (main executable + libraries).

**Additional bounty notes:** Please also expand on chi's comment below, namely, what exactly is the difference between `ghc-options` for *compiling* vs. *linking*. Which are which, and which are never needed in libraries? Maybe you can talk about some of the most important ones, such as the `-threaded` mentioned below.

Comment: I think the libraries will be compiled with their own options. Otherwise, one would need to recompile every library for each executable.

Comment: @chi Isn't that a bit scary? For instance web apps that rely on `-threaded` to work properly. Couldn't these apps become dysfunctional when compiled with libraries without `-threaded`? Hmm.

Comment: `-threaded` affects _linking_, not compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the normal `cabal-install` workflow (and the `stack` workflow built atop it), flags specified in your Cabal file are local to your package, and should not trigger rebuilds. Similarly, options specified with `--ghc-options` on the command line are local to your package.

To your specific questions about `-threaded`, this flag has no effect on library code (as `cabal-install` will tell you), only on executables.

A brief listing of GHC flags is available [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html). In particular, note that `-threaded` is listed under [Linking options](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html#linking-options), with a further link to [Options affecting linking](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#options-linker). From this information, we conclude that `-threaded` is only meaningful for executables because it signals to GHC that we wish to use the threaded runtime. If your package doesn't provide an executable, it has no need for any runtime, threaded or otherwise.

For a high-level explanation of compiling vs. linking: they are two of the steps between source code and executable. Compilation is the process of producing an object file from source code. Linking is the process of connecting the numerous object files which compose your executable. When you compile an executable, it has no idea that a function, say `map` exists unless you defined it, so it just compiles under the assumption that it does. The linking step is where we make all those names available and meaningful. In the case of `-threaded`, we are making the linking process aware of the threaded runtime, which all code calling on the runtime will use.

Since I don't know if you're using the standard `cabal` workflow, `stack`, or the new `cabal.project` workflow, here's a digression to discuss this behavior in the `cabal.project` case.

This is actually an open bug, right now.

The bug is tracked as issue [3883](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/3883) on the Cabal GitHub (and somewhat in the related issue [4247](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4247)).

Relevant to your question, according to current behavior, specifying flags in a `ghc-options` stanza in a `cabal.project` file causes those dependencies to be compiled (or recompiled, as the case may be) with those flags.